# Git pull after local commit

Tags: git, git-bash

I am new to git. I have a few local commits but I want to pull the latest code from the repository and don't yet want to push mine. However git pull, creates unnecessary merges. What is the right way to do this i.e update your local repository without losing the changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is `git rebase`, though you should look at the documentation about that before you start using it.  It is also generally good practice to do development in a local branch to reduce the overhead of this sort of operation.

When you are comfortable, you can use `git pull --rebase` to use rebase rather than merge to resolve differences after the pull -- but, do read the docs first, because this can lose data or cause headaches if misused.  It is a useful but dangerous tool.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I understand that the origin-master and our local repo are two separate branches. So is it normal to see merges when someone pushes something to the repo in between my local commit and my push/pull to/from the repository or should I rebase to avoid this.

Comment: rebase effectively transplants your commits to the new head, as if you wrote them there originally.  It should avoid merge commits.  The "should" part is ... complex.  Effectively, it is a matter of taste.  I recommend you avoid rebase unless you have a good reason to use it.

Comment: It is better to use `--rebase=merges`, so you will not lose your local merges. You can create next alias: `git config --global alias.prb 'pull -v --rebase=merges'` and then `git prb`.